# REGEX - Backsearch code dynamically to find Object.Function

Tags: regex, grep, vb6

I need to find Forms in vb6 using grep which use a certain Objects .Update procedure. The name of this object can change Form by Form. I have a regex which will search forward for the .Update (thanks to a nice man at regex101.com called me-me).

But I cannot take for granted that all declarations are done at the top of the code. I need to have something similar which will search forward OR backwards.

e.g.

searching :

> bla bla bla stuff and things  loads of random code and things
>
> *findme.Update*
>
> set findme = CreateObject("QLHGMUpdateObjects.HGMClientRecord")
>
> bla
>   bla bla stuff and things  loads of random code and things
>
> bla bla bla stuff and things  loads of random code and things
>
> **findme.Update**

With:

\s(\S+) = CreateObject("QLHGMUpdateObjects.HGMClientRecord")(?:\S*+\s*+)*?\K\1.Update

The .update in bold is currently found, but it should also find the one in italics, which i cannot work out.

Please help!

Comment: For example: In Javascript i can use a global search to find all the matches like: `/(\w+\.\w+\s)/g`. The `g` at the end stands for the global search.

Comment: Searching the entire solution is not a problem, the problem is finding the variable name where it does the "set findme = CreateObject("QLHGMUpdateObjects.HGMClientRecord")" and using the variable found there to search backwards

Comment: Couldn't you start the search by finding the first `Update` and thereafter match the name against the following... (I'm not quite sure what you're after so I'm shooting from the hip here ;). E.g. `(\w+).Update.*?set\s+\1\s*=\s*CreateObject\("QLHGMUpdateObjects.HGMClientRecord"\).*?\1.Update`

Comment: The problem with doing that is that it could find many different objects calling a update procedure as it is a data layer function